# How to match RegEx for a not statement

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regexp that I am having trouble matching a date in PHP, but only in a certain format.  My regexp is:

```
[^_][0-9]*[-][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
```

I want to only match

AFM_LU78_8-14-08.pdf

but not

AFM_LU78_08-14-08.pdf

I tried multiple other regexp matches, but have yet to find a way.  Can anyone help?  I feel like I am missing a forward lookahead?

Thanks.

Comment: `[-]` is odd; just use `-`. Also you can use `{2}` to match exactly twice, instead of duplicating your ranges. Also there's no need for a lookahead. It seems that you just need to disallow 0 as the first number, which you can do with `[1-9][0-9]*`

Comment: Hi Dave,  I tried your answer, and removed the brackets around the dash.  Now it is only matching the 08-14-08 not the 8-14-08.  `[^_][1-9][0-9]*-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only looking to extract the date, you should be able to use something like this:

```
(?<=_)[1-9][0-9]?-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}
```

`[1-9][0-9]?` makes sure there's no leading zero in the month part of the date and `(?<=_)` makes sure there's an underscore before the date.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/xA5jX8)

---

I'm not entirely sure whether you realise that in your current pattern, the `[^_]` is what is matching the first number in the date and your pattern would be matching something like `AFM_LU78_abc-14-08.pdf` too.

Otherwise, if the date is not guaranteed to be after an underscore, you might try:

```
(?<=[^0-9])[1-9][0-9]?-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}
```

<sub>[Equivalent to `(?<![0-9])[1-9][0-9]?-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}` which makes use of a negative lookbehind instead]</sub>

Which makes sure there's something other than a number before the date.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/eJ2gA6)

---

`(?<= ... )` is a positive lookbehind that makes sure what's inside is before the pattern that follows.

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
```

That will match 8 but not 08.
If you want to match also 18, use eg:

```
1?[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
```

And that's also:

```
1?\d-\d\d-\d\d
```

Comment: Instead of `(1[0-9]|[0-9])` you can also simply do `1?[0-9]`.